# How to tokenise string and call a function on each token in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a text file with comma delimiter like following

for example str_data.txt

```
aaa,111,bbb
ccc,222,ddd
eee,333,fff
```

I have a bash function to validate each token (i.e. if each token is following some rule or not based on that function will echo true or false. (can leave it like [[ XYZ == "$1"]] also, instead of returning echo) )

for example

```
function validate_token {
  local _rule = XYZ
  if [[ XYZ == "$1" ]]; then
    echo "true"
  else
    echo "false"
  fi
}
```

I want to write a bash script (one-liner or multi-line) to validate all these tokens separately (i.e. validate_token "aaa" then validate_token "111") and finally answer "true" or "false" based on ANDing of each token's results.

Comment: What `XYZ`?  No one of this *token* would match!?

Comment: F.hauri its just for example purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would yo please try the following:

```
validate_token() {
    local rule="???"    # matches a three-chraracter string
    if [[ $1 == $rule ]]; then
        echo 1
    else
        echo 0
    fi
}

final=1                 # final result
while IFS=',' read -ra ary; do
    for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
        final=$(( final & $(validate_token "$i") ))
        # take AND with the individual test result
    done
done < "str_data.txt"

(( $final )) && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

I've also modified your function due to several reasons.

- When defining a bash function, the form `name() { .. }` is preferred.
- It is not recommended to start the user's variable name with an underscore.
  You have `local`ized it and don't have to care about the variable name
  collision.
- When evaluating the conditional expression by using `==` or `=` operator
  within `[[ .. ]]`, it will be better to place the `pattern` or `rule` to the right of the
  operator.
- It will be convenient to return `1` or `0` rather than `true` or `false` for further calculation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, reading line by line and storing the values into an array, then iterating the array calling the function for each value :

```
IFS=","
while read line
do 
   read -ra lineValues <<< "$line"
   for value in "${lineValues[@]}"
   do 
      validate_token "$value" 
   done
done < your_txt_file
```